# How to use form input data as input for axios request in react native?

Tags: javascript, forms, react-native, axios

I need suggestion and help on how to use text from input form as the input for axios request in react native.

Right now I am adding a `SignIn` screen to my app. To retrieve any API for my app, there is a need for token. Before, I just made a one action file using redux to fetch token and store it inside a reducer.

For this case, I am trying to use `email` and `password` from form input while signing in as the data for me to retrieve the token. Long story short, this is my code `SignInScreen.js` right now

```
import React, { Component, AsyncStorage } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { FormLabel, FormInput, Button, Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_TOKEN } from '../actions/types';
import apiConfig from '../services/api/url_config';

class SignInScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: null,
            email: '',
            password: '',
            error: '',
            loading: false
        };
    }

onButtonPress = () => async (dispatch) => {
    let email = this.state.email;
    let password = this.state.password;

    AsyncStorage.getItem('auth', (res) => {
        let TOKEN_URL = apiConfig.url + 'tokens';
        let auth = {};

        if (res === null) {
            auth = {};
        } else {
            auth.push({
                email: email,
                password: password,
                role: 'user'
            });

            console.log(auth);

            axios.post(TOKEN_URL, auth)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.token);
                dispatch({ type: FETCH_TOKEN, payload: response.data.token });
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
                this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
            });
        }
    });    
}


render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Card>
                <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
                <FormInput 
                    placeholder="user@email.com"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                />
            </Card>
            <Card>
                <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
                <FormInput 
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder="password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                />
            </Card>

            <Card>
                <Button 
                    title="Log In"
                    onPress={this.onButtonPress}
                />
            </Card>

        </View>
    );
}
```

My `actions/types`

```
export const FETCH_TOKEN = 'fetch_token';
```

My `tokenReducer.js`

```
import {
    FETCH_TOKEN
} from '../actions/types';

export default function tokenReducer(state = '', action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_TOKEN:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I run this code and when I click on `LogIn` button, there is no result at all. Even the console log too also did not appear. I do not know how should I troubleshoot this problem if there is no console log I can refer to.

As you can see, to get the token, `email` and `password`, as well as the hardcoded value for 'role', need to be pass alongside the `axios.post` request. I am expecting if the request is successful, it will navigate the user to the `Home` screen while if it not, it will navigate the user to the `SignIn` screen again.

My question is, if I want to use the data or text from form input to be pass alongside `axios` request, am I on the right track with this code? If it not, please help me by sharing your suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `axios` instead of default `fetch` in react-native ?

Comment: I first started with `axios` and since I don't really good at javascript, I tend to stay with the first example I learnt which use `axios`. But if you have suggestion other than `axios` and use `redux`, I would love to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using fetch to replace your axios request :

```
fetch(TOKEN_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(auth),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseData => /* responseData.token to access your token */ )
  .catch(err => /* Handle Error */ )
});
```

Maybe connect your component with redux to use this.props.dispatch to dispatch actions instead of asyn func :

import connect function from redux :

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
```

Add at the end of your file :

```
export default connect()(SignInScreen)
```

Remove async func :

```
onButtonPress = () => {
```

use this.props.dispatch to dispatch actions :

```
this.props.dispatch({ type: FETCH_TOKEN, payload: response.data.token });
```

You can also get state from redux store in your component props by using mapStateToProps

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn } // accessed by this.props.isLoggedIn in your component
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignInScreen)
```

Comment: your suggestion on `this.props.dispatch` helped me. I have modified my code a bit and added `this.props.dispatch` instead of `dispatch` only. Now I can use the token saved to do some other request within the app after logged in.